# Can't concatenate when trying to read from file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read from a text file this:

```
Omar,98,99,100
Ali,90,88,85
Ahmad,90,95,100
Mohammad,80,84,88
```

I want to print their name, their grades and finally their average:

```
Omar,98,99,100,99.0
Ali,90,88,85,87.67
Ahmad,90,95,100,95.0
Mohammad,80,84,88,84.0
```

This is the code by now:

```
f = open('infile.txt','r')

for line in f:
    print(line.split(',')[0] + ',' + line.split(',')[1] + ',' + line.split(',')[2] + ',' + line.split(',')[3] + (float(line.split(',')[1]) + float(line.split(',')[2]) + float(line.split(',')[3]))/3)

f.close()
```

And is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you try to append a float `(float(line.split(',')[1]) + float(line.split(',')[2]) + float(line.split(',')[3]))/3` to a string. As the error message says, you can only append a string to a string, so you'll need to convert the float to a string first. Change that line to

```
print(line.split(',')[0] + ',' + line.split(',')[1] + ',' + line.split(',')[2] + ',' + line.split(',')[3] + ',' + str((float(line.split(',')[1]) + float(line.split(',')[2]) + float(line.split(',')[3]))/3)
```

and it should work fine.

However, you shouldn't do the `split` 6 times.  That's the expensive part.
Also, you can use `str.format()` to create the string in a more readable way than using `+` to append a bunch of times.

```
f = open('infile.txt','r')

for line in f:
    parts = line.split(',')
    average = sum(float(i) for i in parts[1:]) / 3
    print( '{0},{1},{2},{3:.2f}'.format(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], average ))

f.close()
```

You can read more about the `format()` function and format strings here: https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/